# How mark selected item from the datatable PrimeNg?

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

I use the selectionMode = "multiple" option of datatable, How mark selected item from the database

Template:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="userLanguage" dataKey="key">
 <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
 <p-column field="languageName" header="Idioma"></p-column>
 <p-column field="languageId" header="Código"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectionMode="multiple"` needs to go into your `p-dataTable` line, not on the column.  Also, you need to define what model you want to store your selected items, such as `[(selection)]="selectedLanguages"` on the same line.  To display certain items as selected, you need to add the languages to the `selectedLanguages` array